# FragmentPagerAdapter Fragment getItem wrong position?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

So for some reason i'm getting a wrong position when i switch tabs on my tabbed activity.

At the bottom of my post you can see my logcat when i start my app, tab 1 and tab 2 their oncreateview is called.

And position 0 switches to 1 even though i'm on tab 1 which must be position 0.

So my problem is that when i change a tab, the wrong data is shown and wrong logcat info.

for example i change to tab 2, logcat shows oncreateview i called from tab3 ?

How can i fix this?

Thanks,

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Log.e(TAG, "Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                Log.e(TAG, "Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab2();
            case 2:
                Log.e(TAG, "Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab3();
            case 3:
                Log.e(TAG, "Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab4();
            case 4:
                Log.e(TAG, "Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab5();
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Get total pages
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
 .activities.MainActivity: Pos: 0
 .activities.MainActivity: Pos: 1
 .fragments.Tab1: onCreateView called!
 .fragments.Tab2: onCreateView called!
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager by default loads 2 tabs. So getItem gets called twice when you first open the app. When you go to tab2, ViewPager loads tab3 in advance so that the scroll will be smooth. See [offscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)).

Comment: Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Check the link that @Nikhil posted

Comment: I tried setting it to 0, doesn't work and i don't understand it.

Comment: I want only to load current tab, and not 2 tabs.

Comment: You can't set it to 0. Minimum is 1. This is because android needs to show the sliding animation from one tab to the next. If the next tab isn't loaded yet, then this animation won't be possible.

Comment: @nupadhyaya So how can i call oncreateview again in my first and second tab? Because it's not called anymore.

Comment: Use onResume instead .. onCreateView is called only when the fragment is created